# Shortcut to switch between design and text in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know some shortcut to switch between design and text in android studio while editing XML layout?

While I can switch from design view to source using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (and need to select something in layout before), I have no way to go back.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can find it in **Preferences->KeyMap**:
`"Select next Tab in multi-editor file"`:

[image]

The keymap depends on the platform:

- On Mac: <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>
- On windows/Linux it is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd>.

**You can change it on the KeyMap panel**.

You can find the buttons to switch between design, text and preview in top right bar:

[image: photo]

With **Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3** you can find the buttons to switch between code|split|design:

[image]

Comment: On windows it is ATL+SHIFT+RIGHT/LEFT

Comment: This answer shows the key command to search for. I usually change such keystrokes to something I can remember.

Comment: Very weird - some shortucts (not coverd by other stuff) doesnt work for this option - for example I can set it to cmd+shift+N but not to cmd+shift+D - eventho both shortcuts are not used. Never happened to me in Intellij before

Comment: In Linux(for me) and probably other platforms a RESTART in required for it to apply the changes.

Comment: May need restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 110):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> works for me. (Windows)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: helped me , +1 from me

Comment: which shortcut is this? please search for `alt+shift+left` and write shortcut name

Answer (score 35):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT/RIGHT</kbd> on windows and ubuntu.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT/RIGHT</kbd> on MAC

Comment: My mouse pointer disappears after switching text -> design -> text, I'm on a mac. why?

Answer (score 15):

Move between **Design** / **Text** tabs in layout’s view:

(Mac) : <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>

(Windows / Linux): <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Good Question:

There are 2 ways:

- If You are on a Activity ( Design or Text)

  1) left click on Text or Design
  2) <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Right/Left</kbd> arrow key
- If You are on a class

  1) click on the name of the activity:
  example: click on activity_actividad2_blank
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad2_blank);

  2) click on Project
   goto to java class
   left click on class and click on "Find Usages" ( Or ALT + <kbd>F7</kbd>)
   double click on result you want to go.

Have a good programming.

Comment: Not a good answer. You are proposing to use the mouse, and shortcuts are designed to avoiding using it

Answer (score 4):

In Windows it's  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>     for Android Studio 3.4

Answer (score 3):

> **(**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**)** + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> arrow keys,

To go back and forth in between Design tab and Text(XML) tab, on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is related to switching between design and xml views, many people may be looking for or interested in how to switch between related XML and Java files. This can be achieved in Android Studio, using the `Related Symbol..`. navigation key mapping.

Depending on your settings and operating system the keyboard shortcut will vary, but you can find out what yours is by looking in `Settings -> Keymap -> Main menu / Navigate / Related Symbol...`

Otherwise try the following keys:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, sir. My MacBook works with your solution (Command + Ctrl + Up) perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd> worked for me on ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

**<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left/right</kbd>** arrow keys worked for me in **Windows 10** in *Android Studio 3.5*.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2023**

[image: new UI]

However still the default shortcut key works fine
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> (on Windows/Linux)

Answer (score 1):

The settings for it is under **Settings->Keymap->Other->Select Next Tab in multi-editor file**, for Android 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to switch to the selected `View` in question. None of the answers did that. So, here we go:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Period.

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 2.3+, one can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are available to switch between design and text window in XML file in android studio 3.6.1. 
Shortcut keys are: ALT + Shift + Left/Right works for me. (Windows)

[image: Top Right side buttons]

Comment: Much better design for android developer by android team.