# Where do I find the text view of Activity_Main?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to learn android app development. In a YouTube tutorial I'm watching, he is working with the text view of of Activity_Main in Android Studio. However, I can't find it. The "Design" and "Text" view are literally right below "Component Tree" Area and somehow I don't have it. Is my screen just too small? Is there a different way to find the text view? I would appreciate any answer thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added a textview. In the Pallette (above the component tree) click Text and then drag and drop a TextView in.

TBH, it is easier using the split code view and adding <TextView to it

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late, but I run into the same problem, but found something on Google, what I think is the answer.
"If You are on a Activity ( Design or Text) 1) left click on Text or Design 2) ALT + SHIFT + Right/Left arrow key."
It opend the text window for me.

Here is where I got it  from: [Shortcut to switch between design and text in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682455/shortcut-to-switch-between-design-and-text-in-android-studio)